# Select values from two tables in sqllite

Tags: sqlite

I have three tables in sqllite database:

```
  topicTable
  -----------
  _id
  topic

  table1
    --------

    _id
    topicid
    topic_text
    description

   table2
   -------
   _id
   topicid
   topic_translation
```

What I am doing is when a clicking particular topic I want `topic_text,description` from
`table1` and `topic_translation` from `table2`

What I have done is:

```
MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE1+" a INNER JOIN "+ TABLE2+" b ON a.topicid=b.topicid WHERE a.topicid="+TOPICID;
Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(MY_QUERY,null);
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What is the problem that you have?

Comment: i am not getting properly.

Comment: what did you get when run that query ?

Comment: i am getting same column values multiple times.

Comment: i think this is not the problem of query this is the problem of your design. make clear what you want and what did you get?

Comment: there is no problem if only one item in table1 and table2 under a topicid

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `topic_text,description` from `table1` and `topic_translation` from `table2` through `table1 topicId`

get the `topicid` of  `table1` and make a simple query like

```
"Select  topic_text,description from table1 where topicid= topicid"
```

similarly for table2

```
"select topic_translation from table2 where table2ID = topicid"
```

at the same time

Answer (score 0):

try this select plz its working with your table

```
t1.topic_text, t1.description, t2.topic_translation from table1 t1 join table2 t2 join topicTable t3 on t1.topicid=t2.topicid=t3._id where t3._id='1'
```